# How to test an Activity with RxBindings and Espresso

Tags: android, rx-java, android-espresso

I use `RxBindings` to listen to the selections on a Tab Layout like this:

```
    RxTabLayout.selections(tabLayout).subscribe(tab -> {
        // do something
   }
```

The Espresso test never stops running. How can I write a test with `RxBindings` used?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need an idling resource that prevents Espresso from finishing. Here's one from a different answer ([IdlingResource Espresso with RxJava](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27138367/idlingresource-espresso-with-rxjava?rq=1))

https://github.com/rosshambrick/RxEspresso

Comment: That doesn't help because we have no onComplete or onError which will be thrown. So the Test didn't finish also.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to test?